# Why this service provider's binding is not working?

Tags: php, laravel, binding, alias, service-provider

I'm trying to alias the base model App\User with another, but the binding defined in the service provider is not working.
In the register() method of AppServiceProvider I have:

`$this->app->bind(App\User::class, App\UserTest::class);`

then when I try to get App\User, I should receive App\UserTest, right? Unfortunately it doesn't.
When I code:

```
$object = app(App\User::class);
dd(get_class($object));
```

I get "App\User" and I don't understand why.
Can someone help me, please?
Thanks.

Comment: first thing ... did you alias `App` in this ServiceProvider? without that alias you are referencing the wrong classes

Comment: Why I should alias `App`? What do you mean exactly? I am reading a book in which there are some example:
```// Asked for Logger, give FirstLogger
$this->app->bind(Logger::class, FirstLogger::class); 
// Asked for log, give FirstLogger
$this->app->bind('log', FirstLogger::class); 
// Asked for log, give FirstLogger
$this->app->alias(FirstLogger::class, 'log');```
I am simply trying to do the first example...

Comment: because PHP namespacing, do you know how namespacing works in PHP? you may be referencing the incorrect classes otherwise

Comment: Oh... yes. I simply miss the initial "\" before App. Thanks :)

Comment: yup that is one way to handle it, or by aliasing `App`:  `use App;` then `App\User` would reference `App\User` and not `App\Providers\App\User` ... good job :)